# How to know if ID correspond to nucleotide sequence or protein with a script

Tags: python, perl, sequence

I have a text file that contains a list of IDs (314 sequences):

```
AVP78031.1
AVP78042.1
ATO98108.1
ATO98120.1
ATO98132.1
...
```

My goal is to make a script (maybe using Python or Perl) to check in the list if all the IDs are nucleotide or protein sequences.
For example:

```
AVP78031.1 -> protein (this is a nucleotide sequence, I change nucleotide for protein to show an example).
AVP78042.1 -> nucleotide
ATO98108.1 -> nucleotide
ATO98120.1 -> nucleotide
ATO98132.1 -> nucleotide
```

Any idea to do a script?

Thank everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are all GenBank or RefSeq accessions, you can use [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) for this as shown below:

```
$ cat accs.txt 
ATO98108.1
ATO98120.1
ATO98132.1
AVP78031.1
AVP78042.1
$ cat accs.txt | epost -db nuccore | efetch -format acc
## no output because none of them are nucleotide accessions
$ cat accs.txt | epost -db protein -format acc | efetch -format acc
AVP78042.1
AVP78031.1
ATO98132.1
ATO98120.1
ATO98108.1
```

**NOTE**: This will work only if the accessions are currently live because `epost` does not find any suppressed accessions. For example:

```
$ cat accs.txt 
NM_002826.3
NM_002826.4
NM_002826.5
$ cat accs.txt | epost -db nuccore -format acc | efetch -format acc
NM_002826.5
```

Here, all three accessions are valid nucleotide accessions but only the last one, NM_002826.5, is alive.

An alternate way is to use the accession prefixes defined [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/acc_prefix/) and come up with an appropriate regular expression query.

Comment: The alternate way (accession prefixes) is a great idea!